# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined offset: 0 laravel

Tags: database, laravel, undefined, offset

I am trying to read from the database and display data into a form but I Keep getting this error.

This is my controller:

```
public function create()
{
    /* this function gets data from the database (marks table) and render it to the view view */

    $data['data']=DB::table('marks')->get();

    if(count($data[0])>0){
        return view('view',$data);
    }
    else{
        return view('view');
    }   
}
```

And this is how I have defined the route:

```
Route::resource('claude', 'viewcontroller');
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `$data` doesn't have an index of `0`.
But it has a key called `data`.
So you have to access it via the key.

It should be

```
 if(count($data['data']) > 0){
     return view('view',$data);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`get()` will return a collection, you can check if its has items by

```
    if ($data['data']->count()) {

        return view('view',$data);
    } else {
        return view('view');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(is_array($data) && isset($data)){
     return view('view',$data);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.